# Check if Point on circle is between two other points on circle

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm looking for a better solution than the 2 algorithms I've currently written (in C) to check if a point on the circumference of a circle is located in the **short arc** created ***between*** two other points on the same circle.

For example: p1 = 358 deg, p2 = 1 deg on the circumference, and I need to know if p3 = .5 degrees is located between p1 and p2 (the solution should regard it as such).

**Clarification**: For this use case I *only* check "betweenness" if p1 != p3 or p2 != p3. In those exceedingly rare cases (floating point numbers) I already have the answer I need.

***This problem is complicate by the fact that sometimes retrograde motion means p2 < p1, and also because p1 and p2 can straddle the 0/360 degree boundary.***

The real world use case is to determine when to continue on and apply an interpolation algorithm for finding exact time of conjunction (occultation) between two bodies in space, one represented by p1 & p2 at two know times and a different object at p3.

Comment: How should we be able to make a `more elegant solution` when we don't know the `the algorithms I've currently written` ?

Comment: Edge conditions:  1) does "between two other points" imply `p3` equals `p1` or `p2` to within? 2) If `p1 == p2`, what does that mean: the whole circle, none of the circle, only that tiny arc?  3) How to represent the whole circle or none of the circle?

Comment: The question is quite clear and specific and I am looking for a more mathematically based solution. I already have two variations of algorithms (like the one by chux below) that have run into issues.... and neither do I need snarky comments about posting example code. I'm not some noob on here looking for easy answers to homework question. I a  looking for an solution I have not already thought of.

Comment: It is theoretically possible that any 2 or even 3 of the points are equal and If the point (p3) being checked is equal to either end of the circle segment (p1 or p2) then it will be considered as "in between".

Comment: @CliffRibaudo So if `p1==p2` and `p1!=p3`, is that within?  Based on your post/comments I think not, yet seek clarification.

Comment: @chux you are correct, if p1==p2 and p3 != p1 then p3 should NOT be considered to be "between".

Comment: @CliffRibaudo That complicates things.  Might as well have a simple `if (p1==p2)...` test in `foo()`. (BTW I think you mean "then p3 should NOT be considered to be "between". ")

Comment: I can certainly add a p1==p2 test.

Comment: You may want to clarify what the result should be when p1 and p2 are exactly 180 degrees apart.  Always true, always false, or depends on some other factor?

Comment: Not relevant to my real world use case where it can never happen. p1 and p2 are the consecutive positions of a planetary body in the circle of the heavens 24hrs apart. No known body moves that fast. I need this to determine if another body is between those two positions to determine if I should use an interpolation routine to calculate exact time of conjunction (occlusion). But thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool within_arc(double p1, double p2, double p3) {
  double cw_p1_to_p2, cw_p1_to_p3;
  cw_p1_to_p2 = fmod(p2 - p1 + 360, 360);
  cw_p1_to_p3 = fmod(p3 - p1 + 360, 360);

  return (cw_p1_to_p2 <= 180) != (cw_p1_to_p3 > cw_p1_to_p2);
}
```

Update: This solution does not consistently handle certain edge cases, like when `p3` is exactly equal to one of the other points or when `p1` and `p2` are exactly 180 degrees apart.

Comment: The only minor niggle I can see is that only one of p1 and p2 is considered  to be within the short arc p1 to p2. That can be fixed by changing the `>` to `>=`, then both p1 and p2 are considered to be within the arc.

Comment: @IanAbbot thanks! I'll double check that but +1 for your thoughts.

Comment: @CliffRibaudo Also be aware that when p1 and p2 are exactly 180-degrees apart, you might need some special handling, depending on whether you want p3 to be considered to be between them or not, like chux mentioned on the other answer.

Comment: @IanAbbott I think return `(cw_p1_to_p2 <= 180) ? (cw_p1_to_p3 <= cw_p1_to_p2) : (cw_p1_to_p3 >= cw_p1_to_p2);` is needed.  "fixed by changing the > to >=" is insufficient as `p3==p2` needs to always pass.

Comment: @IanAbbot is wrong. The suggested change breaks it for the case p1=5, p2=5, p3=5. The posted solution works as posted by Nathan.

Comment: I agree my original version is inadequate. It fails for p1=0, p2=p3=270, for example.

Comment: @chux I thought your suggestion was good at first, but it fails for p1=p3=0, p2=270, for example.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, I agree that's a niggle. Thanks for pointing it out. Unfortunately, your proposed modification also has a niggle. For example, when p1=0, p2=p3=90.

Comment: There are _many_ niggles.  `p3 - p1 + 2 * 360` incurs unnecessary significant rounding should `p3` be very close to `p1` with a +/- difference, effectively making the order irrelevant.  To avoid the round-off error takes more careful coding.  As the level of precision is not specified, cases like `p1=0, p2=p3=90` are the tip of the iceberg or maybe a "who-cares".  As OP is working in degrees [0...360], I doubt much precision is required.

Comment: I don't care about the "niggles". The solutions solves my real-world use case. BUT!! I've just verified there was no need to multiply 360 * 2 and it works as I've edited.

Comment: Actually, thinking more about it last night I realized I got lost in the fray, lol! In the exceedingly rare event (due to floating point math) that p3 is exactly equal p1 or p2. I already have my answer and don't need know if it is "in between". As I mentioned this is to determine when to go to the next step of interpolating exact time and place of conjunction. In the case of p1=p3 or p2=p3 I already have the answer because I know the exact time/position of p1 and p2. Doh! So I think your solution already handles this and I will be checking for equality prior to applying it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the implication that `p1` to `p2` marks a sector in a *clock-wise* fashion:

> [Edit]  OP has since clarified the goal is between `p1,p2` in the shortest direction, clockwise or anti-clockwise.  Leaving this answer as is to represent a solution to the single direction case.

If we assume `p1,p2,p3` are in the range [-360...360]:

```
#include <math.h>
bool within_arc1(double p1, double p2, double p3) {
  return fmod(p2 - p1 + 2*360, 360) >= fmod(p3 - p1 + 2*360, 360);
}
```

Without `fmod()`

```
bool within_arc2(double p1, double p2, double p3) {
  p3 -= p1;
  while (p3 < 0) p3 += 360;
  while (p3 > 360) p3 -= 360;
  p2 -= p1;
  while (p2 < 0) p2 += 360;
  while (p2 > 360) p2 -= 360;
  return p2 >= p3;
}
```

---

If `p1,p2,p3` may be any value

```
bool within_arc3(double p1, double p2, double p3) {
  p1 = fmod(p1, 360);
  return fmod(fmod(p2, 360) - p1 + 2*360, 360) >= fmod(fmod(p3, 360) - p1 + 2*360, 360);
}
```

Comment: Chux thank you for your efforts. ***within_arc1*** does indeed look like a possible solution I didn't think of. I will check it out and if it works then you get the credit for the answer!

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the original request, but this solution seems to ignore the fact that the _short arc_ between p1 and p2 might not be clock-wise.  Don't you need a check that p2-p1 <= 180, and if it isn't, then a check to ensure that p3-p1 > 180?

Comment: I tested within_arc1 in excel and it fails for the case that @nathan mentioned where due to retrograde motion p2 has travelled counter clockwise and is "before". So it fails for case where p1 = 2 and p2 = 1 and p3 = 1.1

Comment: @Nathan This answer starts with "a clock-wise fashion" to cope with the post's open interpretations of such cases.  If we go with the _short_ idea, we have the problem of `p1=0,p2=180`.  So is the within left or right side?  Given the inexactness of FP computations, employing this definition gives dramatic differ answers when `p1,p2` are _near_ 180 out of phase.  Hence I went for a more stable interpretation.  As with planning weddings the details drive one crazy.  Best if OP enumerated various (edge) case results.

Answer (score 0):

Based on chux's answer, this is the best I can come up with that is agnostic of direction:

```
bool within_arc(double p1, double p2, double p3) {
    double d21, d31, d32;

    p1 = fmod(p1, 360);
    p2 = fmod(p2, 360);
    p3 = fmod(p3, 360);
    d21 = fmod(p2 - p1 + 2 * 360, 360);
    d31 = fmod(p3 - p1 + 2 * 360, 360);
    d32 = fmod(p3 - p2 + 2 * 360, 360);
    if (d21 > 180)
        d21 = 360 - d21;
    if (d31 > 180)
        d31 = 360 - d31;
    if (d32 > 180)
        d32 = 360 - d32;
    return d21 >= d31 && d21 >= d32;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the point of your first 3 lines? The values being test are always in the range of 0 >= x >= 360.

Comment: So omit them if not required. They are only there to normalize the inputs.